# Which docker container should have actual job function for RQ serving a web-app?

Tags: docker, redis, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, python-rq

I have a DjangoREST web app that has to queue long-running tasks from time to time.  I am trying to figure out the best approach for partitioning responsibilities.

At the moment, I have 3 docker "containers" not counting a MySQL DB that is serving the web app.  (1) DjangoREST web app, (2) Redis-server, and (3) Rq-Worker

My plan was to have the web-app queue a task for the Rq-Worker, but the API for RQ requires that I supply the actual function as a parameter of .enqueue(), not just its name.  This made me pause, since I've got the function in the code base for the Rq-Worker container.  Can I place tasks on the queue by simply writing directly to the Redis DB without using the RQ API?  Do I need a listener in the Rq-Worker container that listens for connections coming from the web-app and provides a proxy for .enqueue() so that the web-app can tell the Rq-Worker container what to .enqueue?

If I were to just queue a function from my web-app, and RQ tells the worker to run it, does that function have to run in the same container as my web-app?  If I duplicate the code for the function so it's present in both containers will this just work?  Thanks for any guidance here.

Comment: Some potential solutions have been discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/706736/sharing-code-base-between-docker-containers)

Comment: You can actually pass functions by name to `enqueue()`, so you can say `enqueue('builtins.max', 1, 2)` instead of `enqueue(max, 1, 2)`. There is an example in de [docs](http://python-rq.org/docs/) as well.

Comment: Thanks @rvernica -- will give that a try.